# Add dependencies in a separate commit? (best practices)

Tags: version-control, workflow

Say I'm adding some new functionality to an existing C module (it could be any language, but we'll use C for an example). Let's say the module is a binary search tree, and I want to add three new functions: preOrder(), postOrder() and inOrder(), that each traverse the tree (differently) and print the data at each node. Let's also say that these functions each depend on a new dependency, call it libprettyprint.

To add the new dependency to the project, I have to add an #include line to to the module implementation (.c file), and edit some Makefile rules.

I am going to put each of my 3 new functions in separate commits, so they can easily be accepted, changed ore rejected upstream. But there are at least two different ways to deal w/ the new dependency:

Way one:
I would add the #include, change the makefile, and write my first function. Then I would commit that. Then I would write the other two functions and commit each of those separately too. (3 commits total)

Way two:
I could do a really small commit w/ just the #include and the changed Makefile, then commit the three functions in three separate commits. (4 commits total)

Way one seems worse to me because, if the project maintainer/my boss rejected the first commit but accepted the other two, they would have removed the #include and the edited Makefile, and the other two commits would fail to compile. Way two fixes that.

My question is, in the real world, is it worth the extra effort to always use Way two? Or does it just complicate the commit logs and waste time?

Comment: Well, do you know - your *question isn't really SCM-dependent*?! Feel free to reject my retagging anyway

Answer (score 2):

From my POV, you

- Forgot way 0
- Must always keep in mind: used way is **heavy** reviewer- and habits-dependent (that is good in one place is bad in another team)

I (personally) prefer to use and happy to see from coworker-employee side **The Way Zero**:

A logical task fully included in one logically-completed commit. You added three functions, this addition require: 1) include 2) changed makefile 3) added lib file 4) new functions in source?! OK, make it **all in one** commit, in order reviewer can review only one commit and didn't search possibly "dependent".

If, for *any* reasons, your commit doesn't fulfill reviewer, you and he conform best form of implemenation and you make addition final commit "due to the correction of the agreed implementation of ... from revision N"  - less frictions to everybody, clearly visible evolution in perspective